# Geoquery to find out the app user within the radius of 1 km of current location of the user not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, geofire

I want to retrieve a list of all the android app user present within the radius of 1 km of the current location of the user. Below is the code that I am trying, in return its giving me latlong of its own. Help me to figure out where I am wrong.

```
 double radius = 100;

 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(databaseMediCare);
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userLocation");
final List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
databaseReference .child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("geocordinates").child("latitude").setValue(latitude);
databaseReference .child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("geocordinates").child("longitude").setValue(longitude);
databaseReference .child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("availability").setValue(true);
geoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(latitude, latitude));
GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), radius);
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        //showToast("geocodes successfully found");
        data.add(key);
        Location itemLocation = new Location("itemLocation");
        itemLocation.setLatitude(location.latitude);
        itemLocation.setLongitude(location.longitude);
       // Log.d("distance to " + key" is", userLocation.distanceTo(itemLocation) + "");
        Log.i("geocodes Number of users", String.valueOf(data.size()));
    }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {
            Log.i(key, "geocodes left the place");
            data.remove(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            Log.i(key, "geocodes key moved but here");
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
            Log.i("geocodes","All initial data has been loaded and events have been fired!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.i("geocodes", "error occured");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PlaceLikehood instead of Geoquery. [You can see  at this link.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceLikelihood)

PlaceLikehood give you nearby places. And then, you get the distance via Location.distanceTo method.